# Idioms: get short with (one) and see eye to eye

Tags: meaning-in-context

please help me to understand this dialogue:

A: So what you're saying is he got a little short with you?
B: You weren't quite seeing eye to eye?

I know that get short with (one) means To speak or react to one in a curt or abrupt manner, and for the term "seeing eye to eye", it means have similar views or attitudes to something.

Just wonder if this dialogue can be understood as literal meaning? Like: He's shorter than you are and so that you guys can't do the eye contact or talking with each other?

Comment: More context would help this question. Is the dialogue from an Alfred Hitchcock drama or a Marx Brothers comedy? Or from a radio play? Or a novel?

Comment: Sure, anything can be understood literally if someone makes the effort to do so -- I have a  group of punster friends who do this to everything I say for sport. I also have heard there are mental conditions that cause people to understand phrases like this literally. Otherwise, no, there's no chance of a native speaker interpreting either of these expressions literally

Comment: Hi, it's from the Schitt's Creek show. I have no clue about what were they talking about. It's just mentioned these, out of the blue. You can check the full dialogue here: https://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/schitts-creek-2015-EnIE/s1/e13

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible that the dialogue could have been written to have a double meaning: 1) the idioms, as you mentioned, and 2) the fact that the people who are being discussed are not the same height and therefore were literally "not seeing eye to eye." This would be an example of a **pun** and/or a **visual joke**.

In normal speech, unless it was previously made very clear that the people were not of the same height, the literal meaning would not be assumed or even thought about.